# How can I display text on OLED?

Tags: communication, esp32, display, can-bus, oled

I'm trying to print the information, which is received from the other ESP32 by CAN transceiver, on an OLED. The CAN bus is working perfectly, as the 'HELLO WORLD' is already be received. But I can't print the received 'HELLO WORLD' on OLED (also the OLED is work). The code shows below,

```cpp
#include <CAN.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32 // OLED display height, in pixels

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, -1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for (;;);
  }
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);

  Serial.println("CAN Receiver");
  CAN.setPins(16, 17);
  // start the CAN bus at 500 kbps
  if (!CAN.begin(500E3)) {
    Serial.println("Starting CAN failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = CAN.parsePacket();

  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received ");

    if (CAN.packetExtended()) {
      Serial.print("extended ");
    }

    if (CAN.packetRtr()) {
      // Remote transmission request, packet contains no data
      Serial.print("RTR ");
    }

    Serial.print("packet with id 0x");
    Serial.print(CAN.packetId(), HEX);

    if (CAN.packetRtr()) {
      Serial.print(" and requested length ");
      Serial.println(CAN.packetDlc());
    } else {
      Serial.print(" and length ");
      Serial.println(packetSize);

      // only print packet data for non-RTR packets
      while (CAN.available()) {
        Serial.print((char)CAN.read());
      }
      Serial.println();
    }

    Serial.println();
  }
  delay(5000);

  display.clearDisplay();

  display.print((char)CAN.read());

  display.display();
}
```

Comment: To show code in your question, please edit your question, highlight the entire code segment, and click the '{}' button. It will be much easier for potential contributors to read it and answer your question.

Comment: please format your code ... use the `{}` button or put ``` before and after your code

Comment: Are we asking noah to fix his post formatting so he learns how to post a question the includes formatted code rather than editing his question and doing the formatting for him?

Comment: @DuncanC - noah is a "New contributor", so it's possible that one of our users was trying to be nice and help them out. Editing and improving Q+A's is encouraged by Stack Exchange, and there are 3 levels of "badges" awarded for editing them. Users with less than 1000 reputation are given 2 reputation for editing a question. I know of one Arduino SE user that has over 500 reputation and has never asked nor answered a single question. I agree with you about teaching, but I also have to "be nice", and lets not forget about those hardworking volunteers who edit questions to make our site better.

Comment: @VE7JRO, I was tempted to apply the edit myself, but didn't because I wondered if the "please code format your question" suggestions are "teach a user to post" moments. I'm fairly new on the Arduino site, but have a >100K rep on Stack Overflow, so pretty familiar with how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: Just guessing but looks to me like you read the CAN message and print it character by character to the Serial console but you don't save those characters in a buffer as you get them from `CAN.read()`. So when you then try to `display.print((char)CAN.read());` at that point there are no more characters to available for the `CAN.read()` to read so nothing is printed by the `display.print()`. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: @RichardChambers Thanks mate! you save my life.

Comment: @RichardChambers Consider pasting your reply as an answer below, so it can be selected by Noah as the correct answer. For those sweet, sweet internet points ;) (and because then this question won't show up in the "unanswered" list)

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt Thanks for the note. I just didn't think of it.

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing but looks to me like you read the `CAN` message and print it character by character to the Serial console but you don't save those characters in a buffer as you get them from `CAN.read()`.

So when you then try to `display.print((char)CAN.read());` at that point there are no more characters to available for the `CAN.read()` to read so nothing is printed by the `display.print()`.

So what you need to do is to read the characters into a buffer so that you save them after reading them so that you can use the text string for other purposes.